# Word problem - Problem Solving

Tags: problem-solving

My kid is practicing word problem. I have an issue with the question which i m unable to produce any solution. Would be appreciated if any solution is provided.

**QUESTION:**

In the village there were four different types of animals: pigs, sheep, chickens & cows.

- Every fourth animal was a pig
- One out of eight animals was a sheep
- Half of the animals were chickens
- The rest of the animals were cows. There were 50 cows.

How many animals of each type were there in the village?

Comment: You could find the total number of animals first.

Comment: @DavidMitra thanks for the suggestion. Thats what i am am thinking about but i am confused how should i do that. I feel it like a series calculation. But not sure how should i do it.

Comment: Call the total $T$. Express the number of each animal in terms of $T$ (e.g., the number of pigs is $T/4$). Then make an equation...

Answer (score 2):

If we have 8 animals

- pigs are 2
- sheep is 1
- chickens 4
- cow  is  1

So for 50 cows we multiply by 8 = 400 animals

- pigs are 100
- sheeps are 50
- chickens are 200
- cows are     50